# Error al asignar Atributos a un elemento en Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, atributos

Tengo un elemento al cual le necesito agregar atributos, en este casi es el atributo "detailId", pero al momento de agregarle el nombre no me está respetando las mayúsculas.
Al consultar la variable que contiene el nombre del atributo, se encuentra bien, pero una vez que se le asigna, lo asigna como "detailid".

Con esta línea le asigno el atributo:

El valor de m_idTag en muchos casos tiene valores con la nomenclatura lowerCamelCase.
¿Alguien tiene idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pero al momento de agregarle el atributo, lo hace sin respetar la letra mayúcula.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No puedes usar mayusculas en atributos HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero diferenciemos XML de HTML: la especificación de HTML dice que todos los atributos se deben convertir a minúsculas (y que las comparaciones deben ignorar mayúsculas y minúsculas).

Etiquetaste la pregunta como XML, pero al usar el DOM y `setAttribute()`, estás usando el renderizador de HTML de JavaScript... Difícil escaparle.

Una forma de evitarlo, sería especificando un namespace con [setAttributeNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttributeNS), incluso usando `null` como namespace.

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('prueba');

elem.setAttributeNS(null, 'AbCdEfGhI', 'funciona');

//listar todos los atributos
for (let atrib of elem.attributes) {
  console.log(atrib.nodeName, ' = ', atrib.value);
}
//mostrar el tag completo
console.log(elem.outerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="prueba"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la verdad es que no tenía idea que setAttribute() era para HTML específicamente.

Comment: Técnicamente, no es específico para HTML. Funciona con XML... el tema acá es la combinación del documento + `setAttribute()`. O sea, no está tu código completo, pero si usaste `document`, ese es el que lo convierte en HTML. Si en cambio, para generar el documento usaras `document.implementation.createDocument(null, "raiz");`, en ese caso `setAttribute()` respetaría mayúsculas... Pero más fácil usar el código de la respuesta.